# Samba Server OpenVPN very slow

Tags: networking, server, samba, vpn, openvpn

I'm using samba server on my ubuntu 18.04/arm machine. I used my modem for configure openVPN I can share file from another network but my problem is transfer speed very slow. When I try to download file from server I saw 355 kilobyte constant speed and when I try to upload file to server I saw transfer speed between 500-980 kilobyte.

My server Internet speeds are 25 mbps download and 1 mbps upload.
My clinet Internet speeds are 100 mbps download and 10 mbps upload.

Comment: Wired or wireless?  What's your MTU? `ip l | grep $(ip r | awk '/default/ {print $5}' ) | awk '{print $2, $4, $5}'`

Comment: a 10 megabits per second upload would equate to approximately 1 MegaByte per second 980 kilobytes per second upload sounds reasonable.  the 355 kilobytes per seconds sounds very high for your 1 megabit per second upload bandwidth.

Comment: Thanks for comments MTU 1500

Comment: Are u saying my all probiem is my upload speed?